# Can role="rowheader" be used with role="table" or only role="grid"?

Tags: html, wai-aria

I'm a bit confused about the `role="rowheader"`. The specification says this:

> "Rowheader can be used as a row header in a table or grid"

but it also says this:

> "Authors MUST ensure elements with role `rowheader` are contained in, or
> owned by, an element with the role grid."

My table-like component is of `role="table"` because it's not interactive, just purely presentational.

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#rowheader

Comment: It is not clear what is confused for you. **rowheader** could be used only inside a table to mark some cell as **row header**.

Comment: Well the spec says elements with role rowheader must be contained by an element of role grid, but I don't have a grid. I have a table.

Comment: @hornta Just set your table to have `role=grid` or ignore the recommendation as ambiguous is my recommendation.

Comment: Please do **not** use `role="grid"` as mentioned above unless you truly have a grid.  Tables and grids are very different and you can't just interchange them.  A grid has cells that are interactive, meaning you can edit the contents of the cell (like a spreadsheet).  A table can have interactive elements in a cell (like a button) but that doesn't mean the cell itself is interactive, only the button is interactive.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo in the documentation.  While https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#rowheader does indeed say:

> Authors MUST ensure elements with role rowheader are contained in, or owned by, an element with the role grid.

it really should say the rowheader but be contained in a `row`, not a `grid`.  In fact, if your rowheader where a direct child of a grid, it would fail html parsing.

The latest draft version of the doc has this corrected.

https://w3c.github.io/aria/#rowheader

> Authors MUST ensure elements with role rowheader are contained in, or owned by, an element with the role **row**.

Notice in the paragraph prior to the typo, it says:

> Rowheader can be used as a row header in a table or grid

It is perfectly valid to use `rowheader` in both tables and grids.